# Nested Scrolling inside a Viewpager2 inside a BottomSheet

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, bottom-sheet, android-viewpager2

It's 2022, and I'm having the same issue with ViewPager2 that folks had with ViewPager (see [NestedScrolling inside a Viewpager inside a BottomSheetDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41424256/nestedscrolling-inside-a-viewpager-inside-a-bottomsheetdialog) ) - 5 years ago.

Although I'm not using a BottomSheetDialogFragment, just a regular old bottom sheet (with a FragmentContainer).

ViewPager2 is a bit different in that it itself uses a horizontal RecyclerView. BottomSheetView.findScollingChild() sees this as the scrolling child!

So, the approach I took to solving this is:

1. added a page change listener to my ViewPager2 that gets the hosting
   CoordinatorLayout, and calls `requestLayout()` on it after the page change.
2. copied the BottomSheetBehavior class that matches my current material components version (1.5) into my project, renamed it, and made findScrollingChild public.
3. subclassed that copy, and set the sub-class as the behavior on my sheet.

Why sub-class and not just change the findScrollingChild method directly? Well, this way it's relatively easy to update the copy of BottomSheetBehavior when we update our material components.

My implementation of findScrollingChild() in the sub-class checks specifically for a ViewPager2.

If it is, it gets child 0 of the ViewPager2 (the horizontal RecyclerView), and then uses `recycler?.layoutManager?.findViewByPosition(pager.currentItem)` as the view to then search for the scrolling child.

If the view is not a ViewPager2, it uses the same algorithm from the original `findScrollingChild()`

This *basically* works. I have a pager with 2 tabs, one containing a ScollView that has nested scrolling enabled, and one containing a RecyclerView. The bottom sheet expands as its scrolled, and then the contents of the nested child scroll down properly once the sheet is open.

The problem is if after the sheet has expanded if the finger gets lifted, then any attempt to scroll up causes the bottom sheet to close rather then scrolling up -- no matter how far it's been scrolled down. At least this is the case for the RecyclerView in the second tab, I don't have enough content in the first tab at the moment that it actually needs to scroll.

The sheet gets closed with the list still scrolled down several pages (or wherever you stopped scrolling). If however you scroll down -- even just a little bit -- scrolling up works again! And you can swipe a couple times and it will work - until it doesn't, and the sheet moves to the half expanded state.

I'm not sure where this behavior is coming from or how to resolve it. It doesn't happen when the bottom sheet has a direct RecyclerView (no ViewPager2 I'm the way).

I tried disabling swiping in the ViewPager2 thinking it might be interfering with touch events, but to no avail.